# How to assign a Firebase snapshot object to an Angular type

Tags: json, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I've created a Customer service in Angular to get a list of customers from Firebase Live Database as below:

```
  getCustomers() {
       return this.db.list('/customers', ref => ref.orderByChild('name')).snapshotChanges(); }
```

This successfully returns a JSON array.

Then I defined the Customer interface as below:

```
export interface Customer {
  name: string;
  address: string;
  type: string;
  phone: string;}
```

Now, in the component, I'm trying to access the customer information as below:

```
customers: Customer[];
subscription: Subscription;
constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) {
this.subscription = this.customerService.getCustomers().subscribe(customers => this.customers = customers.map(c => c.payload.val()));
```

}

This gives me a compilation error "*Type Unknow is not assignable to type Customer[]*".
my questions are:

1. What's the best way to convert the payload().val() JSON output to Customer type?
2. How do I access Key for each record?(this is required for my page).

Many thanks in advance.

------ An update with the working solution, based on the advice and guidance from Le_Buzz ------

//first I updated the Customer interface to include the field "key' as below:

```
export interface Customer {
  key: string;
  name: string;
  address: string;
  type: string;
  phone: string;}
```

//Declared the customers array as below:

```
customers: Customer[] = [];
```

//Then subscribed to the Observable as below:

```
subscription: Subscription;
  this.subscription = this.customerService.getCustomers().subscribe(cus => {
  cus.forEach(cus => {
    const values = cus.payload.val();
    const key = cus.payload.key;
    this.customers.push({ name: values["name"], key: key, address: values["address"], type: values["type"], phone: values["phone"] })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I will suggest you turn the customer information from firebase into an array, then use the array to build the customer object (there may be a cleaner way, but this is what I can come up with right now). As for the second question, you can fetch the key from right inside your subscribe method. See the below code that worked for me.

Note: I created the following variables:

1. `productArray` to build the result from my subscribe method.
2. `listData` - the dataSource for my table (I rendered the firebase call in a table).
3. `displayColumns` and `columnsTo Display` - these are specific to my table. Your implementation will be different, so you can ignore/modify the codes talking to these variables as you please.

Basically, pay more attention to the first 8 lines below:

```
this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
  list => {
    this.productsArray = list.map(item => {
      return {
        $key: item.key,
        ...item.payload.val()
      };
    })
    this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(this.productsArray);
    this.displayedColumns = Object.values(Object.keys((this.productsArray)[0]))
    this.columnsToDisplay = this.displayedColumns.slice();
    this.columnsToDisplay.push("actions");
  }
);
```

Lastly, depending on the angular version in use, you might want to initialize the customers variable by changing `customers: Customer[];` to `customers: Customer[] = [];`

Kindly mark this as answered, if it solves your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi many thanks for the quick response. This works, but in my version of Angular it gives a warning that "@deprecated — Use an observer instead of a complete callback". I found the following post using the map operator instead :|stackoverflow.com/questions/57939474/… but it returns an Observable and I'm not sure how to read the values from.

Comment: What exactly is deprecated? I used a map in my case, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

If you want to use the observable, you can import observable from rxjs, declare a variable as observable, and then do something like this: `this.items = db.list('items').valueChanges()`. You can also `console.log` at different stages of your code to help with debugging.

Comment: According my code, getProducts().subscribe is depricated. The editor strikes out the subscribe keyword and gives the warning I've mentioned above.

Comment: That is quite strange. I'm using Angular11 and it doesn't throw that error. What version are you using though? Try declaring `subscription` as an observable, i.e. `subscription: Observable<any[]>`

Comment: Many thanks Le_Buzz, with your advice and guidance, I was able to come up with a working solution for me. I've updated the original post above. I'm using Angular 11, Angular/fire 6.1.4 and rxjs 6.6.6